# get data from json file on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I need to get values from distance,distance is under array of elements. I need help retrieving data from different distance.

```
{
    "destination_addresses": [...],
    "origin_addresses": [...],
    "rows": [{
        "elements": [{
            "distance": {
                "text": "1 ft",
                "value": 0
            },
            "duration": {
                "text": "1 min",
                "value": 0
            },
            "status": "OK"
        }, {
            "distance": {
                "text": "62 ft",
                "value": 19
            },
            "duration": {
                "text": "1 min",
                "value": 3
            },
            "status": "OK"
        }, {
            "distance": {
                "text": "253 ft",
                "value": 77
            },
            "duration": {
                "text": "1 min",
                "value": 19
            },
            "status": "OK"
        },.....}]
}],
"status": "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution after big research:

```
NSDictionary* dict = json1[@"rows"][0];
NSLog(@"%@",dict);
NSLog(@"----------------------------------------------");
NSArray *results = [dict valueForKey:@"elements"];
NSLog(@"%@",results);

for (int i =0; i < results.count; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *resultsItems = [results objectAtIndex:i];
//  NSLog(@"%@",resultsItems);
    NSDictionary *resultsItems2 = [resultsItems valueForKey:@"distance"];
 // NSLog(@"%@",resultsItems2);
    miles+=[[resultsItems2 objectForKey:@"value"] intValue];
 // NSLog(@"%d",miles);
}
```